# Axis 2/C on Symbian

Tags: symbian, ws-reliablemessaging, axis2c

I am doing a little bit of research into consuming web services on mobile platforms. In particular I'm currently looking at the Symbian platform. Now, I've seen gSOAP used from a Symbian environment. Has anyone seen or used the C version of Axis 2 on Symbian at all? I'm attempting to explore multiple options, and in particular support for WS-ReliableMessaging is a key factor for a stack. Thank you!